# Java Script Does not work in Chrome but Working Fine in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

In IE my Javascript works, but does not in Chrome or Mozilla. Why not?

My Javascript:

```
    function ValidateOnSubmit() {

        var objGrid = document.getElementById('<%=gvUnitDetails.ClientID %>');
        if(objGrid.rows.length <= 1)
        {
            alert("No Units to Open!");
            return false;
        }

        var i;
        var isChecked = false;

        for(i=1;i<objGrid.rows.length;i++)
        {
            var objcbSelect = objGrid.rows[i].cells[var_COLIDX_gvUnitDetails_SelectAll].firstChild;

            if(objcbSelect.checked == 1)
            {
                isChecked = true;
                break;
            }
        } 

        if(isChecked == false)
        {
            alert("Please Select at least one to Open!");
            return false;
        }

        return confirm('Are you sure you want to Process?');
    }
```

and Grid View:

```
<asp:GridView SkinID="grid_header_fixed" ID="gvUnitDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="false" DataKeyNames="UnitNoID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" Checked="true" OnClick="javascript:return UncheckActivityGrpAll(this);" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectHeader" runat="server" Checked="true" onClick="javascript:return CheckUncheckActivityGrp(this);" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SN." ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%#Container.DataItemIndex+1 %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Project Structure" DataField="ProjectStructureDisplayName"/>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Unit Type" DataField="UnitType" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Unit Sub Type" DataField="UnitSubType" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Unit Category" DataField="UnitCategory" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Unit No" DataField="UnitNo" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: var objGrid = document.getElementById('<%=gvUnitDetails.ClientID %>');

Comment: Please explain what the expected behavior is, and what behavior you're actually seeing.